# R, Format date on X axis using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

After aggregating, "filtering" and parsing a column with date and hours by using as.Date, also transforming it by using melt function, my data looks like this:

```
DATE    variable value
1 13-09-20  Billete_50 20405
2 14-09-20  Billete_50 19808
3 13-09-20 Billete_100 27787
4 14-09-20 Billete_100 20361
5 13-09-20       Total 48192
6 14-09-20       Total 40169
```

I want a linear graph to show the data, but it looks like this:
[image: Linear plot]

It's in spanish, I'm sorry, but the date is almost the same, it may say only September (Sep), but it is showing October, January, April, July, then back to October.

This is my ggplot line:

```
ggplot(plotCajero1Melted, aes(x=DATE, y=value, col=variable)) + geom_line() +xlab("Fecha") +ylab("Saldo") +ggtitle("Cajero 1")
```

What should I do? It's something with the date? I was thinking in the year, it is represented in a short way, probably it is making ggplot to have a weird behavior, or maybe a ggplot option that i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, your date format is not read as it should be (it seems to be read as Year-Month-Day).

You can modify the date format for example by using the function `dmy` from `lubridate` package to indicate `r` to read the date as Day-Month-Year:

```r
library(lubridate)
df$DATE <- dmy(df$DATE)

ggplot(df, aes(x = DATE, y = value, color = variable))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you so much, you saved my day. I applied for a javascript+python+sql Job, there said "R desirable but not required" and the test they sent me is only about R, very funny haha. I started learning about it 23 hours ago.

Comment: Haha ! Good luck then ;) Fingers crossed

Comment: dc37 Thak you :D